# VMA101 Mega 2560 upload error

Tags: arduino-mega, upload

I have a Velleman VMA101 Arduino Mega 2560.

https://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=435498

When I connect it to my computer, I can see it on Port COM18 with a yellow triangle, which means something is wrong. On IDE I had COM3 available, so I went to device manager and chaged the port to COM3.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The drivers are installed correctly when I installed the Arduino IDE 1.8.7.

I tried to get the board's info and I got this:

```
BN: Unknown board
VID: 04E8
PID: 6860
SN: Upload any sketch to obtain it
```

After that, I tried to upload an empty project to see whether it will work or not. It didn't work and I got this error message:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino14/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM3
         Using Programmer              : wiring
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

What's wrong with my board?

How can I solve this problem?

> ***The board was working perfectly for months***

Comment: Uninstall the device and let Windows find it again.

Comment: I uninstalled everything (devices, drivers), then installed everything again. The computer recognized the device and installed correctly the driver but I got "code 52" which looks related to unknown signature of the driver. How could this be solved?

Comment: Embrace the dark side and upgrade to Windows 10? No driver needs to be installed then.

Comment: found solution here https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=317769.0 thanks anyway